# border off in internet explorer in only one resolution, works in Firefox and Chrome

Tags: css, internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox, border

I have a border line around a div (box with content).  2px left and right, 3px bottom.  This works perfectly fine on Chrome and Firefox.  This also works perfectly well in Internet Explorer.. except for one screen resolution.  The problem is the left side of the border moves to the right side inside the actual box.  I didn't even realize this issue on my computer, since in my screen resolution it is fine.

However, another web designer I work with has it at a different resolution and it fit perfectly around the box but is moved a bit more to the right.. only for one resolution.  I even use ctrl + 0 to see it on my resolution, it's fine.  I zoom in and out and it has a problem when I zoom in at one point.  It's the same case with the other guy looking at his screen except that it's in his original resolution for him.

Is there a way to fix this?  I've looked around but have been unable to find someone having a similar issue, though perhaps that's due to me wording it improperly when looking for a solution.

Comment: Show us the code or create a simple example using http://jsfiddle.net please specify which version of IE and which resolution. A screenshot would also help to illustrate the issue

Comment: - It is Internet Explorer 11.
- unfortunately my screen print button doesn't work.
-

Comment: I would just say it's pixel snapping. I wouldn't worry about it unless it's messing up your layout. Chrome sometimes has the same problems.

Comment: It's not messing the layout as in everything else is in place other than the border crossing the div box but otherwise it is ok.  It looks a bit unprofessional but it's a roll over button.  Rather irritating and would like to figure out a solution if possible.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent the border from increasing the size of the box. Use CSS style `box-sizing:border-box`

Comment: that wasn't the question at all, but thanks for the comment :)

Comment: The border cross the the other element because the width+border give an unexpected total width. Try box-sizing like I said.

Comment: Hey Thanh, I tried it out, but unfortunately the border still shifts to the right side when I zoom in that resolution in IE11.

Comment: Each browser must have their own way to calculate the zoom pixel. You should spy the width/height of each element. Beside what's the point of zoom in and out anyway, it's not reliable to determine the resolution of a screen

Comment: The issue is that the other web developer`s native resolution screen on his computer is set to the one that currently moves the border to the right.  So we have slightly different ones, it isn't as if I zoom in/out with everything I code. :)  Otherwise we would have likely not found this little bug.  

I did check out the length/width and everything is ok in all variations of IE11.  Quite a particularly weird bug.

Comment: Try to post an image. I can't imagine what it's like. Beside you can reduce the size of some div to make it fit the page